# How to use google guice appropriately and efficiently

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am working on a web site and we use the Google Guice for the Dependence Injection. Now we just use the guice to inject the constructor of the services implicitly by adding the `@ImplementedBy` annotation. The code is such as:

```
@ImplementedBy(ServiceImp.class)
public Interface Service{...}

public ServiceImpl{@Inject constructor()....}

Guice.createInjector().getInstance(Service.class)
```

I think we may need to set the stage and  the scope  or other factor involves in the performance. But I am not sure about all of this.

Could anyone share some experience?

Comment: Can you fix some of the wording in your question? And what are you asking about with respect to performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [Best practice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/MinimizeMutability)  section will help you.